# Compiling C++ program that uses SWI-Prolog Interface

Tags: c++, g++, swi-prolog, ffi

I am compiling the program found [here](http://electricbacon.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/calc-example-using-swi-prolog-and-c/), and at runtime I get an error:

Here is what I do to compile it:

```
$ g++ -I/home/jpthomps/Desktop/pl-6.0.2/src main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib/swipl-6.0.2/lib/x86_64-linux -lswipl
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:39: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:20:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Then when I try to run the compiled program:

```
$ ./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libswipl.so.6.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do I need to add something to my .cpp file to tell it where the libswipl.so.6.0.2 file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you see is related to the inability of the running `a.out` to find your dynamic library. There are several system-dependent ways to deal with the issue. For example, on [Linux you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) to include the directory where `libswipl.so.6.0.2` is located.

---

Although the compilation warnings are not related to the runtime error, it is still a good idea to fix them:

```
static const char * av[] = {"calc.pl", NULL};
....
const char * expression = "pi/2";
```